# im getting that type of error send_mail got multiple values for argument fail_silently

Tags: html, django, forms, templates

[image: I'm writing a simple little program ... when I'm trying to email this info. from that form, I got that type of error]

I'm writing a simple little program ... when I'm trying to email this info. from that form, I got that type of error
I'm writing a simple little program ... when I'm trying to email this info. from that form, I got that type of error
[image: send_mail() got multiple values for argument 'fail_silently']

Comment: In the future, please include the source code not as a screenshot, but as properly formatted text - this makes it easier for people to help you. See [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `send_mail` [has the following signature:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#send-mail)

```py
send_mail(
    subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, 
    auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None
)
```

That means your call is equivalent to the following:

```py
send_mail(
    subject='Follow up required for - ' + name,
    message=phone,
    from_email=address,
    recipient_list=message,
    fail_silently=scheldule,
    auth_user=time,
    auth_password=email,
    connection=['fidtestwebsite@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Maybe you can already see what is going wrong - the order you are passing in the parameters is important. Here, you are passing in the `message` as `recipient_list`, which I would guess is not your intention, and the error "send_mail got multiple values for argument fail_silently" comes from passing `scheldule` in place of `fail_silently` as [a positional argument, and then again at the end as a keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument). There can only be one value for each argument.

Comment: that was helpful 