# How to call multiple variables in send_mail() function

Tags: python, django

How do I call multiple variables in send_mail() message parameter function like employeeid, name, email, fromplace, toplace, vehicle, duration.

Also, I have stored all the data in the Script tag with the names given above and not in the views.py file.

I have a similar problem: [im getting that type of error send_mail got multiple values for argument fail_silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747474/im-getting-that-type-of-error-send-mail-got-multiple-values-for-argument-fail-si)

```py
def maintenance(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        employeeid = request.POST.get('employee-id')
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        fromplace = request.POST.get('from-place')
        toplace = request.POST.get('to-place')
        vehicle = request.POST.get('vehicle')
        duration = request.POST.get('duration')

        send_mail('Employee Form',
                  employeeid,
                  settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                  ['a@gmail.com'],
                  fail_silently=False)
    return render(request, "maintenance.html")
```

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'maintenance' %}" class="employee-form" >
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h3>Search By ID To Autofill</h3><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input id="user_id" name="employee-id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee ID"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fplace">From Place:</label>
                        <input type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                                id="fplace"
                                name="from-place" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tplace">To Place:</label>
                        <input type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                                id="tplace"
                                name="to-place"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="request">Request:</label>
                        <select name="vehicle" id="request">
                            <option value="cab">Cab</option>
                            <option value="bus">Bus</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="hrs">Duration/Hours:</label>
                        <select name="duration" id="hrs">
                            <option value="8h">8 Hours</option>
                            <option value="od">Only Drop</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-success" />
                </form>
```

JavaScript Code which has the data stored in:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log('Hi ready');

   $(function(){
   $('#user_id').autocomplete({

    source: [{
      label: "01",
      name: "A",
      email: "a@gmail.com",
    }, {
      label: "02",
      name: "b",
      email: "b@gmail.com",
    },{
      label: "03",
      name: "C",
      email: "c@gmail.com",
    },{
      label: "04",
      name: "D",
      email: "d@gmail.com",
    },{
      label: "05",
      name: "D",
      email: "d@gmail.com",
    }],
    select: function(e, ui){
        $('#user_id').val(ui.item.label);

        $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
        $('#email').val(ui.item.email);
        return false;
    }
   });
   });
    });
</script>
```

Error:'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

```py
def maintenance(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        employeeid = request.POST.get('employee-id')
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        fromplace = request.POST.get('from-place')
        toplace = request.POST.get('to-place')
        vehicle = request.POST.get('vehicle')
        duration = request.POST.get('duration')

        send_mail('Employee Form',
                  [employeeid, name, email, fromplace, toplace, vehicle, duration],
                  settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                  ['a@gmail.com'],
                  fail_silently=False)
    return render(request, "maintenance.html")
```

Comment: Please [do not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), add it to the post in a [code block]. Is `send_mail()` your code? Or a library? What exactly should be done with the POST variables?

Comment: Are you trying to send a html as email or something like that?

Comment: I am trying to send a mail with multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

The message should be a string not a list.

Look for django documentation:[send_mail() documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/email/#send-mail)

```
def maintenance(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      employeeid = request.POST.get('employee-id')
      name = request.POST.get('name')
      email = request.POST.get('email')
      fromplace = request.POST.get('from-place')
      toplace = request.POST.get('to-place')
      vehicle = request.POST.get('vehicle')
      duration = request.POST.get('duration')

      mail_content = f"{employeeid}, {name}, {email}, {fromplace}, 
                       {toplace}, {vehicle}, {duration}"

      send_mail('Employee Form', 
                 mail_content,
                 settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                 ['a@gmail.com'],
                 fail_silently=False)
return render(request, "maintenance.html")
```